# Composite C1 Deployment Error with the extenal C# function?

Tags: .net, iis, c1-cms

I try to deploy a Composite C1 WebSite to IIS by published a Visual Studio Project but after deployment,  the extenal C# functions were not found. Here's the picture of the error:

"**XSLT Function call markup for failed to parse ('The Function named 'Composite.Functions2.GetPage' is not known. Ensure it exists with the exact spelling and casing you provided.').
Please see server log for more details.**"

Please give me the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was discussed here - http://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/388950

**The solution:** When you make a publish in VS it copies all the files in a solution that have an appropriate "Build Action" in project file. In your case those new .cs files either aren't a part of solution, or don't have the necessary build action. You can either add the files to the solution or use some other ways of deploying a C1 website (for example - just copy the files.)